# Select all elements except specific element with className by using plain Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am implementing a simple website which has a toggle sidebar. I want to make the sidebar be hidden when I clicked somewhere on the page except the sidebar. So I think that I should get all elements on the page except a element that has sidebar class. Is there any way to do like that with plain javascript? JQuery has :not() select for this, but I'm trying to not using JQuery... :(

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll()` has `:not()` as well.

Comment: You don't need to get all the elements. The duplicate question has answers that show how to do it more efficiently with plain JS.

Comment: @Barmar Oh, Thanks very much. Because of my poor English, I didn't think that I should have tried to search like that. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> JQuery has :not() select for this

It's actually [CSS](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#negation), although jQuery extends it to allow all selectors (CSS's `:not` only allows a [simple selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#simple-selectors-dfn) within the `:not`). Yours is a simple selector, so you can use `:not`:

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll(":not(.sidebar)");
```

**However**:

> I want to make the sidebar be hidden when I clicked somewhere on the page except the sidebar.

I wouldn't implement this by setting an event handler on every element. Instead, I'd set a handler on `document` and then check to see if the event passed through the sidebar on the way to the document, e.g:

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if (e.target.closest(".sidebar")) {
        return; // The click passed through the sidebar
    }
    // close the sidebar
});
```

That uses [`Element#closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest), which is present on all modern browsers and can be polyfilled for obsolete ones.

Comment: Thx!! It works well. :)